# Join pandas series while keeping new indices

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 pandas.Series:

```
s
-9999.00    26371
240.00       1755
138.99          2

s2
-9999.00    26371
240.00       1755
113.03          6
100.00          4
```

I have tried concat:

```
-9999.00    26371
 240.00      1755
 138.99         2
-9999.00    26371
 240.00      1747
 113.03         6
 100.00         4
```

and s+s2:

```
-9999.00    52742
 100.00       NaN
 113.03       NaN
 138.99       NaN
 240.00      3502
```

but I need the output that adds values of existing indices and keeps new indices if they appear, so a mix of concat and '+'. How can I do that? My expected output is

```
swanted:

-9999.00    52742
 100.00         4
 113.03         6
 138.99         2
 240.00      3502
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `.add` method with a `fill_value`:

```
>>> s = pd.Series(index=[-9999, 240, 138.99], data=[26371, 1755, 2])
>>> s2 = pd.Series(index=[-9999, 240, 113.03, 110], data=[26371, 1755, 6, 4])
>>> s.add(s2, fill_value=0)
-9999.00    52742
 110.00         4
 113.03         6
 138.99         2
 240.00      3510
```

Or you could align the two first, and then simply add them with `+`:

```
>>> s.align(s2, fill_value=0)
(-9999.00    26371
 110.00         0
 113.03         0
 138.99         2
 240.00      1755, -9999.00    26371
 110.00         4
 113.03         6
 138.99         0
 240.00      1755)
>>> s, s2 = s.align(s2, fill_value=0)
>>> s + s2
-9999.00    52742
 110.00         4
 113.03         6
 138.99         2
 240.00      3510
```